# Android - Reading available details from an EMV credit card

Tags: android, nfc, emv

I am looking to add functionality to an app to read off publicly available information from EMV credit card's. The app I am working on already has NFC support where it's currently reading information from non credit-card types.

This is something I have no past experience in, so I'm a little unsure where to begin.

I am already able to detect the presence of my own credit card through an `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` intent-filter which one of my activities is handling it's just what I can do next to request available details from the card I am unsure of.

I have seen lots of posts about putting together APDU commands, but I was wondering if there are any ready made Java libraries that facilitate the exchange of these with the card and return an object of sorts with properties such as card number, expiry, etc.

I have seen one such library - https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment

But wondered if there any other alternatives, or are there any worked examples someone can refer me to for further guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may consider looking at [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this library already but it seems to lack any documentation

Comment: The best documentation you can get are the [EMV Books](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223)